# Python Multi-Index: Finding cordinates with level 2 index, DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, multi-index

I have an empty DataFrame with Multi-Index index and columns. I also have list of strings that is cordinates of second level indexes. Since all of my second level index are unique, I am hoping to find cordinates and input values with my list of strings. Take a look at below example

```
df=
       DNA      Cat2                                 ....   
       Item     A   B   C   D   E   F   F   H   I   J   
DNA   Item
Cat2  A         0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 
      B         0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 
      C         0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 
      D         0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 
      E         0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 
      F         0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 
....

str_cord = [(A,B),(A,H),(A,I),(B,H),(B,I),(H,I)]
#and my output should be like below.

df_result=
       DNA      Cat2                                 ....   
       Item     A   B   C   D   E   F   F   H   I   J   
DNA   Item
Cat2  A         0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0 
      B         0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0 
      C         0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 
      D         0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 
      E         0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 
      F         0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 
      H         0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
....
```

It looks kinda complicated, but all I want to do is use my str_cord[0] as my cordinate for df_result. I tried with .loc, but it seems like I need to input level 1 index. I am looking for the way that I do not have to input Multi-Index level1 and find cordinates with level2 strings. Hope it make sense and thanks in advance! (Oh the data itself is very big, so as efficient as possible)

Comment: Very difficult to reproduce this dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
for i, j in str_cord:
    idx = pd.IndexSlice
    df.loc[idx[:, i], idx[:, j]] = 1
```

Sample:

```
L = list('ABCDEFGHIJ')
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Cat1','Cat2'], L])

df = pd.DataFrame(0, index=mux, columns=mux)
print (df)
       Cat1                            Cat2                           
          A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J    A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J
Cat1 A    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
     B    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
     C    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
     D    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
     E    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
     F    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
     G    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
     H    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
     I    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
     J    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
Cat2 A    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
     B    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
     C    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
     D    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
     E    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
     F    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
     G    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
     H    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
     I    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
     J    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

---

```
str_cord = [('A','B'),('A','H'),('A','I'),('B','H'),('B','I'),('H','I')]

for i, j in str_cord:
    idx = pd.IndexSlice
    df.loc[idx[:, i], idx[:, j]] = 1
```

---

```
print (df)
       Cat1                            Cat2                           
          A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J    A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J
Cat1 A    0  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0    0  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0
     B    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0
     C    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
     D    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
     E    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
     F    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
     G    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
     H    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0
     I    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
     J    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
Cat2 A    0  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0    0  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0
     B    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0
     C    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
     D    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
     E    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
     F    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
     G    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
     H    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0
     I    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
     J    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```